# Can hlint enforce strict record fields?

Tags: haskell, hlint

Is it possible for `hlint` to enforce the following:

If I have

```
data Foo = Foo
  {bar :: Bar
  , baz :: Baz
  , quux :: Quux
  }
```

but it should be

```
data Foo = Foo
  {bar :: !Bar
  , baz :: !Baz
  , quux :: !Quux
  }
```

Is there a way for hlint to enforce that?

Comment: So you want to make all fields strict for all records you define?

Comment: yes, unless I explicitly ignore the hlint rule

Comment: Notice there is an extension [`StrictData`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/strict.html#strict-by-default-data-types) which you can activate in you cabal file of moduel `{-#LANGUAGE StrictData#-}`